# Notation for expressing a straight chain of $n \choose 2$ identity statements

Tags: logic, notation, predicate-logic

Given the glossary $Dx$: $x$ is a dog, we can make the following translations:

- "there is *at least* one dog" - $\exists x Dx$.
- "there are *at least* two dogs" - $\exists x \exists y (Dx \land Dy \land x \ne y)$.
- "there are *at least* three dogs" - $\exists x \exists y \exists z (Dx \land Dy \land Dz \land x \ne y \land x \ne z \land y \ne z)$.

In general, if we want to say that there are at least $n$ dogs, we need $n$ variables, $n$ existential quantifiers (one for each variable) prefixed to a conjunction of $n$ atomic formulas of the form $D\underline{x}$ and $n \choose 2$ identity statements (one for each unordered pairing of the $n$ variables). I understand this as saying "you can choose at least $n$ distinct objects that have the property of being a dog."

- "there is *at most* one dog" - $\forall x \forall y ((Dx \land Dy) \implies x = y)$.
- "there are *at most* two dogs" - $\forall x \forall y \forall z ((Dx \land Dy \land Dz) \implies x = y \lor x = z \lor y = z)$.
- "there are *at most* three dogs" - $\forall x \forall y \forall z \forall w ((Dx \land Dy \land Dz \land Dw) \implies x = y \lor x = z \lor x = w \lor y = z \lor y = w \lor z = w)$.

In general, if we want to say that there are at most $n$ dogs, we need $n+1$ variables, $n+1$ universal quantifiers (one for each variable) prefixed to a conditional. The antecedent of this conditional is a conjunction of $n+1$ atomic formulas of the form $D\underline{x}$. The consequent of this conditional is a disjunction of $n + 1 \choose 2$ identity statements (one for each unordered pairing of the $n+1$ variables). I understand this as saying "for any $n+1$ objects you choose, if they all have the property of being a dog, then at least two of those objects must be the same objec."

**But I was wondering if there was a way to express this pattern more visually using symbols rather than words?** Something like $\exists x_1 \exists x_2 ... \exists x_n (Dx_1 \land Dx_2 \land ... \land Dx_n \land ?)$, but I'm not sure how to express the unordered pairs part (hence the question mark).

Comment: This is the sort of thing that natural languages are much better at than strict mathematics.  It is easy, and you have done so, to write the statement in English.  For a specific $n$ it is possible to write it in logic, but it quickly becomes tedious.  In first order logic it is usually not possible to say there are infinitely many dogs.

Comment: Thanks @RossMillikan, I'm new to predicate logic, so wasn't sure if such a notation existed.